# How to delete specific file in powershell for current logged in user?

Tags: powershell

I have 5 names of files that I want to delete from a users computer. The paths could be "`current logged in username\desktop` or `downloads` or `documents` folder.

How do I add `$env:UserName` to the code to see if file exist if so then delete? I appreciate any help. thanks

I have this so far but it does not work.

```
If (c:\users\$env:UserName\downloads\text.txt $strFileName){Remove-Item $strFileName}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have this If (c:\$env:UserName\desktop\text.txt $strFileName){
 Remove-Item $strFileName
}

Comment: Please add you code to the question as additional info is often missed in comments.

Comment: `$env:USERNAME` will be the current user's name (that's you, if you're the one running the script).

Comment: It's unclear what your if should compare/test? The expression in parentheses is expected to be a boolean (or coerced to).

Answer (score 0):

You can test for the existence of a file/folder using [Test-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6):

`Test-Path -Path 'C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\text.txt'`

You can incorporate environment variable in the path:

`Test-Path -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\text.txt"`

An alternative technique when using 'special' folders is the [GetFolderpath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.8) method of the .NET [Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment?view=netframework-4.8) class:

`Test-Path -Path "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop'))\Text.txt"`

Check here for the full list of folders supported by this method: [Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

So, to test for and delete a file (path stored in `$strFileName`), do something like this:

```
if(Test-Path -Path $strFileName) {
    Remove-Item -Path $strFileName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you really mean c:\username\desktop which would be `$Env:USERNAME` or if you want to delete from the user profile which would be `$env:USERPROFILE`
Delete the `$UserPath` variable as required below

```
$FiletoDelete = 'test.txt'
$UserPath = $env:USERNAME
$UserPath = $env:USERPROFILE
$PossibleFoldersPaths = @("Downloads","Documents","Desktop")


$PossibleFoldersPaths | ForEach {
    $DeletePath = Join-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $UserPath -ChildPath $_) -ChildPath $FiletoDelete
    If (Test-Path -Path $DeletePath) {
        Try {
           Remove-Item -Path $DeletePath -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        Catch {
            $_
        }
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host "No file found at $DeletePath"
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great. can I add 5 file names to it instead of one?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually really easy using `Get-ChildItem` and piping it to `Remove-Item`. You can use the built in `$home` variable to indicate the user's profile path, and specify that you want to look at everything in the desktop, downloads, and documents folders. Past that you use `-Include` to specify your file names, and you're all set.

```
$arrFileNames = 'File1.txt','File2.log','File3.exe'
$arrPaths = "$home\Desktop\*","$home\downloads\*","$home\documents\*"
Get-ChildItem -Path $arrPaths -Include $arrFileNames | Remove-Item
```

That will find any of the files at any of those locations, and delete them if they exist.